# other parts of the code execute before $http.get completed

Tags: javascript, http

I want to send a get method to find the server date and then get that value for a variable and use them in my latter part of the program but everytime i use the following way it executes latter part of the code before. how to stop this?

```
var syncedDate;
    $http.get("../../system/info").then(function (response) {
        response = response.data;
         syncedDate = response.serverDate.split("T")[0] + " (" + response.serverDate.split("T")[1].split(".")[0] + ")";
        console.log(syncedDate);
    });
    if (respo == "error") {
        syncHistory.push({
            syncDate: syncedDate,
            notification: "Error In Network",
            instance: instance,
            metaDataFilterd: filData,
            response: respo
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

this executes asynchronously and non-blocking inherently. you may want to move your 'latter' code within the callback function (response). I'm assuming you are using angularjs, you may also want to use the errorCallback instead see

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http